# How to define the function type that takes five time the same argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I would like to know whether it is possible to define a function type that takes `n` arguments, just by knowing `n` and the type of these arguments.

For example, we could have something like :

```
template<int N> struct test {
  typedef void(*)(E,E,E,...) fct; //E is written N times
};
```

In C++11 it is easy to instanciate a variadic template with N times the same type using recursivity, but I have no idea how to translate that into a valid function pointer type.

As I type those words, the solution came to me.  I will answer myself, so the knowledge can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simpler solution, you could just make the function take a `std::array<T, N>`.  Initialize the array directly within the parentheses to make it look mostly like a normal function call:

```
foo({1, 2, 3})  // to pass a std::array<int, 3>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was typing I suddenly envisioned the solution in C++11.
The trick is to use a generic `Fct` template type and specialise it a function type using variadic template type for the argument of the function "specialisation".

```
template< typename Fct, typename NewArg > struct functional_append_arg;
template< typename Ret, typename... Args, typename NewArg >
struct functional_append_arg< Ret(Args...), NewArg >
    { using type = Ret(Args...,NewArg); };
template< typename Ret, typename Arg, int N> struct functional_repeat_arg;
    { using type = functional_append_arg< functional_repeat_arg<Ret,Arg,N-1>::type, Arg >::type; };
template< typename Ret, typename Arg> struct functional_repeat_arg<Ret,Arg,0>;
    { using type = Ret(); }
```

Comment: yeah, Generic template and the corresponding specialization is the critical tech. of C++ template facility

Comment: I would step back one, and write code that appends to a parameter pack (of a `template<class...>class`), then build the signature from a return value and `tuple` in anothet `template`.

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the indices trick here again in lieu of the recursive variadic technique.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct repeat {
  private:

  /* Map any index to T. */
  template <std::size_t>
  using T_ = T;

  /* Function pointer that takes Ts. */
  template <typename... Ts>
  using Fn = void (*)(Ts...);

  /* A function returning void (*)(T...). */
  template <std::size_t... Is>
  static Fn<T_<Is>...> impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>);

  public:

  /* Get the return type of impl. */
  using type = decltype(impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>()));

};  // repeat

static_assert(std::is_same<repeat<int, 5>::type,
                           void (*)(int, int, int, int, int)>::value, "");
```

Comment: Very smart !  However you declare useless static functions per `T` and per `N` and you rely on the compiler to remove them, of which I'm not very confident.  I did not know std had `integer_sequence`s, though.

Comment: There's one static function which I'm only using to perform `decltype` on it (hence no definition). I don't understand what you're not confident about? The static function is private to the struct and the compiler won't generate any code for the static function. Even if it did, it can't be called.

Comment: Well I'm building a library so I thought the compiler would build as much code as possible.